# splitting annotated images with json file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, annotations

to make it short, I'm trying to split annotated images into train - val - test. I've used the libary splitfolders however it only split the images while the annotated file (.JSON) didn't.
so I tried to use annotated_image libary as I've seen it can do that however I've had an error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-2345d5e2fe5c> in <module>()
      6 RANDOM_SEED=1337
      7 IMG_PATH= '/content/Untitled Folder'
----> 8 annotated_images.split(IMG_PATH,'/content/', seed=1337, ratio=(0.8,0.15,0.05))
      9 
     10 import splitfolders

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/annotated_images/split.py in list_files(directory)
     26     if len(files) == 0:
     27         files = glob.glob
---> 28     if len(files) == 0:
     29         files = glob.glob(directory + "*.*")
     30     return files

TypeError: object of type 'function' has no len()
```

I'm using Google Colab tho
can anyone help please? or if there is anyway to split images + their respective annotations together!
thank you.
PS: I'm kinda new to python and all, not very familiar with it.

PS2: the code:

```
import annotated_images

RANDOM_SEED=1337
IMG_PATH= '/content/Untitled Folder'
annotated_images.split(IMG_PATH,'/content/', seed=1337, ratio=(0.8,0.15,0.05))
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple oversight. Add an extra slash to the end of your path like this

```
IMG_PATH = '/content/Untitled Folder/'
```